# Screen flickers on boot up on Dell XPS 15 with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dell, 22.04, visual-artifacts

I have a Dell XPS 15 9575 and on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04, I can't get to the login screen. The screen only shows vertical lines, as shown in the picture below:

[image: picture showing the screen problem]

I had this machine running in the past with Ubuntu 20.10 with no issues.

Any idea what might cause this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem on the same device. I can fix it by plugin in an external monitor via USB-C. It will stop flickering after I plugged it in and stays "normal" when I unplug the monitor. After a reboot I have the same problem again. I also checked whether it was a problem of the graphical grub bootscreen, it was not.

Answer (score 0):

A fix: In your "/etc/default/grub" uncommend "GRUB_GFXMODE=" and put "1920x1440" as its value. Then do a "update-grub" and the fragments on bootup should be gone. If not try "1024x768". If you are not able to access the operating system at all you can do the same thing by accessing the grub console on start up and entering "videoinfo 1920x1440". If you are changing the grup display resolution that way you might have to do the steps above from within the operating system again, to set the resolution permanently. Do not worry, this does not set your whole operating system to 1920x1440p, only the grup bootloader.

A temporary fix: add "nomodeset" to the grub boot parameters (in "/etc/default/grub" at 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""'. Then do a "update-grub" to permanently use it). As far as I understand it tells the kernel to disregard the graphics driver. This does fix the problem, however it comes with several drawbacks. First you cannot use fractal scaling anymore. Second as far as I can tell the system runs not very smooth and rendering new screen content is slow, especially scrolling content is painful. It works, but it ain't great.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! unfortunately I don't have that machine to test it on anymore. However, I hope someone could benefit from this. cheers bro

Comment: I have this very machine and can confirm Mettigel4_1's fix worked for me. The bug has been present ever since upgrading to 22.04 and using 5.15 kernels. My workaround before finding this answer was simply using the 5.13.0-41 kernel.